# `Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module` Not Available in New Module Wizard

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to add another shared module in my KMP project. I chose `File > New > New Module...`

[image: File > New > New Module...]

The wizard that appears doesn't show the `Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module` template  :

[image: Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module]

I have the KMM plugin installed already:

[image: KMP Plugin]

And I am using `Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1`:

[image: Android Studio Version]

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Go to IDE Settings and Search for Multiplatform, toggle "Enable Experimental Multiplatform IDE Features" and you are good to go